# Exclude folder from being copied

Tags: vb.net, file, copy

Hi I know how to copy files from one folder to the next, but I've run into a snag when we need to exclude a folder. More specifically the ".svn" folder. I've tried using Not SourceDir.Name = skipDir but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is my code. Thank you for the help.

```
    Private Sub CopyDirectoryContents(sourcePath As String, destinationPath As String)
    Dim SourceDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)
    Dim DestDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(destinationPath)
    Dim skipDir As String = ".svn"

    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    Try
        If Not Directory.Exists(sourcePath) Then
            MsgBox("The directory path entered does not exist. Please re-enter your source directory path", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Title:="Missing source directory")
            Return
            txtSubfolder.Focus()
        End If

        If Not Directory.Exists(destinationPath) Then
            MsgBox("The destination directory does not exist. Creating folder for it.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Title:="Missing folder")
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath)
        End If

        Dim totalFiles As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count
        Dim fileCount As Integer = 1

        For Each filePathString As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Dim fileInfoItem As New FileInfo(filePathString)
            Dim newFilePath As String = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileInfoItem.Name)

            If SourceDir.Exists And Not SourceDir.Name = skipDir Then
                If File.Exists(newFilePath) Then
                    Dim result As Integer = MsgBox("File already exists in destination folder. Do you want to overwrite it?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, Title:="File already in folder")
                    If result = DialogResult.No Then
                        Continue For
                    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                        statusText = "Replacing found image"
                        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(count, statusText)
                        File.Copy(filePathString, newFilePath, True)
                    End If
                Else
                    File.Copy(filePathString, newFilePath)
                End If
            End If
            fileCount = +1
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error has occured. Please contact the system administrator. Exception: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Presumably not, otherwise you'd be able to tell us WHY `Not SourceDir.Name = skipDir` didn't work. Put a break point on that line and actually look at the values being used. If that doesn't work as expected then obviously at least one of the values being compared isn't what you expect it to be. Debug and see what the actual values are. You will likely be able to fix the issue for yourself then. Also, why use `Not SourceDir.Name = skipDir` rather than `SourceDir.Name <> skipDir`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think the answer is in OP's name :P

Comment: You have a number of problems here. The first thing to fix is that you're using `SourceDir` for the comparison: that name never changes. You need the path of `filePathString` or `Path.GetFilenName(fileInfoItem.DirectoryName)`. Or use  `DirectoryInfo` instead of `Directory` the enumerate the files (which you need to enumerate just once :). The `BackGroundWorker` role here is undefined and it's not clear where/when you created it. You should include that part of code, too. Btw, are you sure you want to copy all files to a single path without preserving the original structure?

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your input. I'm not familiar with DirectoryName and DirectoryInfo. I'm not familiar with using those code but I'll research it. Yes I need to copy all files listed in a list and copy them to a single path. The problem is the writers make all sorts of sub folders in their graphics folder. I'm given an XML document and I have to retrieve those graphics. So that is why I thought this tool would work. Place everything in one folder then your not traversing hundreds of sub folders. I'm sure there's a better way to do this. I just don't know how. Any suggestions are appreciated